# RSA encryption/decryption using java API is generating BadPaddingException:Data must start with zero

Tags: java

```
public class RSAAPI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton encrypt,decrypt,clear,exit;
JLabel plainlbl,encrlbl,decrlbl;
JTextArea   plainText,encrText,decrText;

static KeyPair kp;
static KeyPairGenerator kpg;
static Cipher cipher;
static PublicKey publicKey;
static PrivateKey privateKey;

public RSAAPI()
{
    setLayout(null);

    encrypt=new JButton("ENCRYPT");
    decrypt=new JButton("DECRYPT");
    clear=new JButton("CLEAR");
    exit=new JButton("EXIT");

    plainText=new JTextArea();
    encrText=new JTextArea();
    decrText=new JTextArea();

    plainlbl=new JLabel("PLAIN-TEXT");
    encrlbl=new JLabel("ENCRYPTED-TEXT");
    decrlbl=new JLabel("DECRYPTED-TEXT");

    plainlbl.setBounds(30,20,120,15);
    plainText.setBounds(30,40,400,150);

    encrypt.setBounds(180,195,90,15);
    encrlbl.setBounds(30,215,120,15);
    encrText.setBounds(30,235,400,150);

    decrypt.setBounds(180,390,90,15);
    decrlbl.setBounds(30,410,120,15);
    decrText.setBounds(30,430,400,150);

    clear.setBounds(80,585,90,15);
    exit.setBounds(250,585,90,15);      

    add(encrypt);
    add(decrypt);
    add(clear);
    add(plainlbl);
    add(decrlbl);
    add(encrlbl);
    add(exit);
    add(plainText);
    add(encrText);
    add(decrText);

    encrypt.addActionListener(this);
    decrypt.addActionListener(this);
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    exit.addActionListener(this);

    setSize(500,650);
    setVisible(true);
    decrypt.setEnabled(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    byte[] inData,outData;
    if(ae.getSource()==encrypt)
    {
        try{
            inData= plainText.getText().getBytes();
            outData=RSAAPI.encryptData(inData);
            encrText.setLineWrap(true);
            encrText.setText(new String(outData));
            decrypt.setEnabled(true);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==decrypt)
    {
        try{
            inData= encrText.getText().getBytes();
            outData=RSAAPI.decryptData(inData);
            decrText.setLineWrap(true);
            decrText.setText(new String(outData));
            decrypt.setEnabled(false);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==clear)
    {
        plainText.setText(null);
        encrText.setText(null);
        decrText.setText(null);
        decrypt.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else if(ae.getSource()==exit)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static byte[] encryptData(byte[] inData) throws Exception
{
    publicKey=kp.getPublic();
    cipher=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(inData);
}

public static byte[] decryptData(byte[] inData) throws Exception
{
    privateKey=kp.getPrivate();
    cipher=Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,privateKey);
    return cipher.doFinal(inData);      
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    kpg=KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    kpg.initialize(1024);
    kp=kpg.genKeyPair();
    new RSAAPI();
}
```

}

Comment: -1: pasting your program without any surrounding description is not a good way to ask questions.

Comment: This isn't a question, it's a dump of code with very little context. If you can improve it, please flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find that you are getting a discrepancy between the `byte` array that you have encrypted and are setting as a string in your `JTextArea` and the `byte` array that you are trying to decrypt.

Try to use Base64 encoding for displaying your encrypted data as such:

```
encrText.setText(new String(new BASE64Encoder().encode(outData)));
```

and

```
inData = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encrText.getText());
```

Comment: +1 for a solution. The problem is most likely happening because the OP relies on default encoding when converting between string and bytes, and the encryption process produces bytes that can't be converted in the default encoding (very likely with UTF-8).